# Массив из typedef struct

Tags: c, массивы, структуры

Здравствуйте, мне нужно сделать массив из адресов серверов.
Я сделал структуру-тип:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char ip[4];
    unsigned short port;
} serveradr_t;
```

И делаю так:

```
serveradr_t get_server_list() {
    serveradr_t q[5];
    q[0].ip[0] = 34;
    q[0].ip[1] = 64;
    q[0].ip[2] = 145;
    q[0].ip[3] = 56;
    q[0].port = 27015;
    return q;
}

int main() {
    serveradr_t servers[] = get_server_list();
    printf("%d:%d", servers[0].ip[1], servers[0].port);
    return 0;
}
```

Но получаю ошибку, может кто правильный пример написать?
А то я не могу у себя в голове это все переварить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция имеет тип возвращающего объекта заданный как объект структуры, то есть скалярный объект

```
serveradr_t get_server_list() {
^^^^^^^^^^^
//...
```

В то время как функция возвращает указатель на структуру (на первый элемент локального массива, что может стать причиной неопределенного поведения программы)

```
serveradr_t get_server_list() {
    serveradr_t q[5];
    //...
    return q;
    ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

В C функции не могут иметь в качестве возвращаемого типа массивы.

Кроме того массивы не могут инициализироваться выражением, не заключенным в фигурные скобки (за исключением символьных массивов, инициализируемых строковыми литералами). Поэтому данное предложение

```
serveradr_t servers[] = get_server_list();
```

в любом случае неверное.

У вас есть два выхода. Либо передавать в функцию массив в качестве аргумента и его инициализировать в функции, как, например,

```
void get_server_list( serveradr_t q[], size_t n ) {
    q[0].ip[0] = 34;
    q[0].ip[1] = 64;
    q[0].ip[2] = 145;
    q[0].ip[3] = 56;
    q[0].port = 27015;
}
```

Либо динамически выделять память под массив в функции и возвращать указатель на этот массив. Например,

```
serveradr_t * get_server_list() {
    serveradr_t *q = malloc( 5 * sizeof( serveradr_t ) );
    q[0].ip[0] = 34;
    q[0].ip[1] = 64;
    q[0].ip[2] = 145;
    q[0].ip[3] = 56;
    q[0].port = 27015;
    return q;
}
```

Если массив имеет размер, известный при компиляции, то вы можете заключить его в другую структуру и использовать эту структуру в качестве возвращаемого значения из функции.

Если размер массива известен только во время выполнения, то вы также можете использовать структуру с гибким массивом в качестве ее последнего члена и возвращать эту структуру из функции.